# In angular html form, lowercase id or name becomes Upper case (e.g. make as Make) when calling in Typescript file in Angular Component. Why is that?

Tags: typescript, angular8

I have an Angular component whose html file has a form with `select label` where `id="make"`, change function and two way binding `(change)="onMakeChange()" [(ngModel)]="vehicle.make" name="make"`. I am implementing cascading drop-down list such that, upon selecting the item from the first drop-down list, the second drop-down list will be populated.

Now the thing is, when I am fetching values from the html form into my component.ts file, its given an error of undefined at `const selectedMake = this.makes.find(m => m.id == this.vehicle.make);`. I have solved the issue by looking at the object in browser console. Actually, `this.vehicle.Make` is what it should be, `Make` with capital M. I have use make with small m everywhere in my code. But it somehow gets converted to uppercase.

I don't understand the reason of this. If I understand where does it happen, I will make sure to keep the code correct at the first place.

I am pasting the code of Make.Component.ts file, Make.Component.Html and make.service.ts file with it.

Thank you!

**Typescript file:**

```
import { MakeService } from './../services/make.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-vehicle-form',
  templateUrl: './vehicle-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./vehicle-form.component.css']
})
export class VehicleFormComponent implements OnInit {
  makes: any[];
  models: any[];
  vehicle: any = {};

  constructor(private makeService: MakeService) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.makeService.getMakes().subscribe(makes => this.makes = makes as any);
  }

  onMakeChange() {
    const selectedMake = this.makes.find(m => m.id == this.vehicle.Make);
    this.models = selectedMake.models;
  }
}
```

**Html File:**

```
<h1>New Vehicle</h1>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="make">Make</label>
    <select id="make" class="form-control" (change)="onMakeChange()" [(ngModel)]="vehicle.make" name="make">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option *ngFor="let m of makes" value="{{m.id}}">{{m.name}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="model">Model</label>
    <select id="model" class="form-control">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option *ngFor="let m of models" value="{{m.id}}">{{m.name}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

**service file:**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MakeService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getMakes() {
    return this.http.get('/api/makes');
  }
}
```

If the answering person need anything else such as dotnet core controller or how am I sending the api, let me know please.

Comment: You chose to use `make` in your code. But the actual name used at runtime is dictated by the JSON you get from the **server**. If the server sends you apples, you can't pretend that the apples are bananas. You need to accept that they are apples, and deal with what you get. And please, stop using `any`. Define interfaces describing the shape of the objects you get from the server. The whole point of TypeScript is to have typed objects. using any completely defeats the point.

Comment: so, does this come with json that whatever case I use, it change it to upper case?

Comment: No. Nothing is *changed* to uppercase. It is in uppercase in the JSON. The server sends you something like `{"Make": "Toyota"`}. Not something like `{"make": "Toyota"}`. So pretending that the property is named `make` wont work. it's named `Make`, not `make`.

Comment: So, basically, I have the model class named as Make, that is why, when the json object was sent, it was sent as Make. am I correct?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the model class". I have no idea of how the server generates the JSON, because I don't have access to the code of your server. But that's irrelevant: if your server sends JSON looking like `{"Make": "Toyota"}`, then it will be parsed to the JavaScript object `{Make: "Toyota"}`. The JSON.parse() method that makes this deserialization from JSON to objects has no idea that you would prefer the property to be named `make`, and it doesn't care. So you have to accept what the server sends, as is. And if you don't like it, you need to change the server code.

Comment: I get it. Thank you for giving time! :)